# App Crash with void androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setId(int) In Android Studio

Tags: android

Below is the error I am getting on my Log In screen, it had never happened before and I have not changed that screen at all since I completed it. This occurs when I try to run the app, it does not run it and says "App keeps stopping".

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.inventorylive, PID: 2528
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.inventorylive/com.example.inventorylive.Log_In_2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setId(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setId(int)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:991)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.inventorylive.Log_In_2.onCreate(Log_In_2.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Below is the Kotlin code

```
package com.example.inventorylive

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_log_in_2.*


class Log_In_2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in_2)

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        btnSignUp1.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this,Sign_Up2::class.java))
        }

        btnLogin1.setOnClickListener {
            if(Username.toString() == preferences.getString("username",null) && Password.toString() == preferences.getString("password",null)){
                btnLogin1.setOnClickListener {
                    startActivity(Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java))
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username or Password is Incorrect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And below is the app gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.inventorylive"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Below is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main"
    tools:context=".Log_In_2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:text="@string/login_now"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2.5sp"
        android:text="@string/please_login_to_continue_using_our_app"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Username"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtSettings" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Username"
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Username" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnLogin1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Password"></RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin1"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp1"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogin1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06999999" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If anything else is required to see to solve this problem let me know and i will edit my post

Comment: post your layout file, also did you try to clean / rebuild project?

Comment: @DarShan its a bit long but there you go

Comment: did you try clean & rebuild project? or might also try Invalidate Cache & Restart.

Comment: Can you share the manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in @DarShan's comment above, cleaning & rebuilding the project fixed the issue for me.